# Change all eight numbers to 1

Tags: mathematics, strategy

A solitaire game starts with eight numbers arranged in a circle. Each is either 1 or −1, and the choice is arbitrary. In each move, one can multiply any three adjacent numbers by −1. Prove that one can make all eight numbers equal to 1.

---

<sub>This puzzle comes from a Leningrad Mathematical Olympiad.</sub>